# Remove show/hide password icon in Safari

Tags: css, input, safari, passwords, webkit

Is there any way to disable or remove show/hide icon in Safari which appears when you start typing symbols into the input with "password" type? I could easely do it in IE/EDGE by adding to my CSS following rule:

```
input[type=password]::-ms-reveal,
input[type=password]::-ms-clear
{
    display: none;
}
```

But I wonder how can I do the same for Safari. Nothing has been found here

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
input[type=password]::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button,
input[type=password]::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: none !important;
   pointer-events: none;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a `<div>` with `background-color: white` and `position: absolute` above it.